# Communicate a button click event with sockets

Tags: php, apache, sockets, ubuntu, websocket

**Desire:**
I have a device or micro-controller i'll call it a mc that I need to communicate to when a web page button is clicked using sockets.

```
MC1
<button id ='on1' name='mc1'>On</button>
<button id ='off1' name='mc1'>off</button>
```

**Details:**
What I am trying to accomplish is when a button is clicked pass the info to the mc.

**What I Tried:**
Currently I can listens to a port and can write data to the mc as well as receive data. 
To do this im starting a file though the server php cli. The file contains these basic socket functions.

```
 $socket = @socket_create_listen("port#");
 $client = socket_accept($socket);
 socket_write($client, $msg);
 socket_read ($client, 256);
```

the mc then connect to the server at the port#

**Problems:**
Im having difficulties understanding how to bridge the gap between my php web page with the  button and passing the data that the button has been clicked to the mc.

**Attempt at a Solution:**
Can i have the file that listens to the port run and then in a seperate file write to the client?

**additional notes**: The MC LAN I would like to avoid setting up port forwarding and the external ip sometimes changes. For these reason I had choose to have the MC establish the connection to the server thus allowing the server to write to the MC without needing port forwarding and a non changing ip address.

Thanks
JT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to create a simple program (php is fine) that runs in a web server (like apache, but whatever).  Whenever it is called, it synchronously opens a socket to your MC and sends the data.

You wouldn't write any code to open a listening socket, but your php would open a client socket to the MC with [socket_connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-connect.php), send the data, then close the socket.. then you could return the status back to the web client.

Comment: The issue with this is that it requires my MC to have port forwarding on and an ip that does not change... I was hoping to avoid this issue by having the MC initiate the connection thus the server now having the ability to write to the MC avoiding the port forwarding and ip issue. None the less I appreciate ur reply!

Comment: @tman while this can be done within a web server (not sure how to do it best within common PHP frameworks), the easier way might be to have another process running on the same machine that has the MC connected to it all the time.  Then, when you get the button click within your web framework, just "tap" this other process somehow (sockets, filesystem, whatever) and have it send your data.  You would need to make this as secure as you need to, but it stops you from having to write a webserver yourself (hard) or use some advanced features in some other web server.

Comment: Ahh maybe you could elaborate more on the "the same machine that has the MC connected to it all the time" statement. The MC directly connects to the internet so there is not other machine. I have considered putting a small OS ...like a r pi but im not sure how this would solve the problem... What process are you suggesting that could be ran?

Comment: run a permanent connection to another process on the same machine as your web server (or on a well-known IP/port somewhere).  Then, whenever you get the right signal (user pushing a button or whatever) that you can detect using normal PHP web page design, call to this intermediary process which knows to trust this call (or is authenticated) and relays the message to the actual MC.  Basically just use a third-process as an intermediary.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the assumption that your web server can't directly open a connection to your MC, and that your MC can only create an outbound connection to a static IP. You want a loop in your php cli code, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-read.php#73509 - change `usleep (1000000);` to `sleep(1);` and after the sleep command, check a database (or the existence of a file) for whether any messages should be sent to the MC. Then on your frontend php script (html), you could write to your database or create a file when the user `POST`'s back for the button click.

Comment: Ahhh the dreaded loop lol... You were right with your first assumption ... I'm doing this to avoid having to set up port forewarding and insuring the client ip is the same. My research showed me that to avoid this issue have the MC start the connection and then all the problems are avoided. The issue I have with the loop is that it's a lot of stress on the server and database. I just really hate to be using all those resources just to check if a file has changed. It also adds latency I would assume which is really un fortunate. I really do appreciate your reply though!